# Coffeescript array.sort(a,b) generates failing JS

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

I am working with coffeescript (version 1.11.1) and I ran into something that I'm struggling to describe.  I was simply trying to sort an array of objects by a field, which I can do like so:

```
data.sort (a,b) ->
    if a.name < b.name then -1 else if a.name > b.name then 1 else 0
```

This produces the following javascript:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Awesome.  But in my first attempt I did this instead:

```
data.sort(a,b) ->
    if a.name < b.name then -1 else if a.name > b.name then 1 else 0
```

And the generated javascript is for that is:

```
data.sort(a, b)(function() {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Which, because javascript is so helpful, fails silently (at least in Chrome) and causes the surrounding function to return prematurely.  A little frustrating but I'll get over it.

First I want to confirm that is expected behavior.  I think it probably is and I have some vague thoughts bouncing around my skull about why it does this but I was hoping to get a firmer understanding.  How should this be described or what terminology is relevant for this feature of the language?

Comment: I would find that level of white space sensitivity troubling, if it isn't a bug *(and if I used CoffeeScript)*.

Comment: @squint the more I think about it, the reason I think this is happening is that a function can return a function in js so there needs to be a way to distinguish the two.  Coffeescript has syntactically meaningful whitespace as (ala Python) so that comes with the deal.  Really it's the JS engine that is the problem here.  Why it doesn't log out that a/b is not defined is unfathomable to me.

Comment: The JS engine isn't the problem. JS engines will tell you that `a` or `b` are not declared, if indeed they're not. If there's no *ReferenceError*, then those identifiers are declared. I'm not a Python developer but I know it's indentation sensitive. Didn't realize that its white space sensitivity extended to the level that you show here.

Comment: Fails silently? I'd really expect it to throw an exception about an array being not a function, which matches your experience of "returning prematurely". You really should get an error in the console if nothing in your code is catching the exception.

Comment: @Bergi Nope.  nothing at all.  I put a log statement before, and after the sort and there there was one after the method returns.  When it runs, the only thing in the console was the statement before and the one after the method returns.  Silent failures in javascript are really common in my experience.  I'm surprised this surprises you.  A simple google search on "javascript silent failure" tells me I am not alone in this.

Answer (score 4):

That is the expected behaviour.

---

CoffeeScript supports all of the following:

- `(a, b) -> 5` notation for *functions*,
- `-> 5` notation for *functions* without arguments,
- `f(a, b)` notation for *function calls*, and
- `f a` notation for *function calls* (implicit parentheses).

So how do you call the result of a function call `f(a, b)` with a function parameter `-> 5`?

The answer is—

```
f(a, b) -> 5
```

—which as you've noticed, looks rather similar to—

```
f (a, b) -> 5
```

—which translates to calling `f`, passing the function `(a, b) -> 5` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is expected but the real question is how to describe the feature of taking the stuff that comes after the space and turn it into a parameter?  Or a link to the relevant description of how that syntax is interpreted.

Comment: A description of the [function literal syntax is here](http://coffeescript.org/#literals). I've heard of that feature referred to as "implicit parentheses". The implementation is perhaps best read as [annotated source for the language grammar](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html). [The function literal is defined in it here](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html#section-24).

Comment: @JimmyJames I'd say "(white)space as function application operator"

Comment: @Anko Thanks for the links.  Function literal helps but I'm still not sure what you call the feature that takes the thing after the space and uses it as a function parameter.  There is a similar feature in Ruby.

Comment: I think it would be a good update to add `do f` to call a parameterless function to the list of ways how you can call functions in coffeescript.

Comment: I meant in the `CoffeeScript supports all of the following` list in your answer huh

Comment: @AntK Ah, that's what you mean. I disagree. This list only contains the language features necessary to answer the question. An exhaustive list of every way of writing functions or function calls in CoffeeScript would be much longer and irrelevant to the question.